# change div background image on click (issues with image path)

Tags: javascript

On click of a div i am passing an image path to a function and in that function i assign that path to the `background-image :url("imagePath")`.

Somehow the absolute path is being passed and not the actual path.

This is my div

```
function update(image)
{
    $("#divImage")..css('background-image', 'url('image')');
}
```

but that somehow never worked
can someone please help me on this

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. The url of the image is not proper javascript.

Comment: When you say "absolute path" vs. "actual path" what do you mean? Do you mean a fully-qualified path (with http(s)://domain/and/path/to/file.jpg), or /path/to/file.jpg? Other than the obvious JS issue in the code above (which Neuro already commented on), I'm just not clear whether that necessarily solves the real issue, as even that JS problem would not change what path is sent, rather it would throw an error in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#divImage").css("background-image", "url("+image+")");
```

**Notes:**

1) You have double `..`
2) you need `+` around the variable

Cool.

*Edit*: people keep editing my posts for no reason - was there any reason to change the `)` with full stops?! Bizarre...

Comment: I think +images+ should have single around it as it will nest improperly otherwise.